# JavaScript - Why is this code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, opacity

I am using JavaScript and CSS to try and make a masic messagebox using an `iframe`. What I would like to happen is the document to have an `opacity` of `0.4`, and the message box to show. However, none of that happens. What should  I do?

My JavaScript

```
function messageBox(text)
{
    document.style.opacity = 0.4;
    document.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=40);';
    var box = document.createElement('iframe');
    box.setAttribute('id', 'msgBox');
}
```

My CSS

```
 #msgBox
 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:9999;
    color:white;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 1px #444;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4m9d/

Comment: please create a fiddle and check.

Comment: Try this with a DIV first and then try an iFrame. The problem could be the iFrame

Comment: Have you tried to debug this yourself?  What does your HTML look like?  How are you calling `messageBox`?  Do you see any errors in your console?  Are you sure that `messageBox` is even being called?

Comment: @AurA - http://jsfiddle.net/a4m9d/

Comment: I don't think the `document` has a `style` property.  That doesn't make sense.  You probably want to target the `<body>`.  Try `document.body.style`.  P.S. On your JSFiddle, change `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat very correctly pointed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function messageBox(text){
    document.body.style.opacity = 0.4;
    document.body.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity="40");';
    var box = document.createElement('iframe');
    box.id='msgBox';
    document.body.appendChild(box);
}
```

although I would recommend using a div instead of an iframe, for performance and flexibility

Comment: Thanks - how would I make it that all the rest of the document has a lower opacity and the iFrame doesn't?

Comment: wrap the rest of your page in a div, set the opacity on that div

Answer (score 1):

The `document` doesn't have a `style` property.  Only elements have a style, and `document` is not an element.

You want to target the `<body>`, so try `document.body` instead.

```
function messageBox(text) {
    document.body.style.opacity = 0.4;
    document.body.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity="40");';
    var box = document.createElement('iframe');
    box.setAttribute('id', 'msgBox');
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/a4m9d/3/